# How to use multi (i need 2) columns as grouping columns for postgresql crosstab?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I want to construct a crosstab in postgress, which has 2 columns for grouping, the inst and date, and the event is for categories.

```
    From:
inst    date    event       times
inst1   jan01   high_cpu    5
inst1   jan01   high_io     3
inst1   jan01   net_slow    4
inst1   jan02   high_cpu    6
inst1   jan02   high_io     2
inst1   jan02   net_slow    3
inst2   jan01   high_cpu    2
inst2   jan01   high_io     2
inst2   jan01   net_slow    5
inst2   jan02   high_cpu    3
inst2   jan02   high_io     6
inst2   jan02   net_slow    1

Want output like this:
inst    date    high_cpu    high_io     net_slow
inst1   jan01   5           3           4
inst1   jan02   6           2           3
inst2   jan01   2           2           5
inst2   jan02   3           6           1
```

how to construct the postgres sql code so that i have both inst and date columns for grouping?
i checked the doc seems mostly talking about single grouping column, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use filtered aggregation:

```
select inst, "date",
       sum(times) filter (where event = 'high_cpu') as high_cpu,
       sum(times) filter (where event = 'high_io') as high_io,
       sum(times) filter (where event = 'net_slow') as net_slow
from the_table
group by inst, "date"
order by inst, "date"
```

Comment: thanks a_horse_with_no_name, although your query doesn't have the so called "crosstab" key word, but it works pretty good, and logic is quite clear, i love it, thanks bro!!